# Android : Trying to get a bitmap from color code.. It returns null

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to create a bitmap from color code defined as drawable in colors.xml

Whenever I try to create a bitmap from it this line throws a null pointer exception.

How can I create a bitmap from specific color code. Either used as `R.color` or `R.drawable`

Answer (score 0):

program:

```
   Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(48,48, Config.ARGB_8888);    
          Canvas canvas =  new   Canvas(result);    
   // .....
  canvas.drawBitmap(result, rect, rect, paint);
```

xml:

res/drawable:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
     <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
      android:src="@drawable/bg_toolbar"  
       android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Comment: I have a color code in R.color and R.drawable .... I want to create a bitmap from it... and use it in program. I think your code does opposite

Answer (score 0):

```
protected Bitmap genBitMapforAnim(String itemCode, int size) {  
         String text = itemCode.length() >= 5 ? itemCode.substring(0, 5) : itemCode;  
         Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(size*2,size*2, Config.ARGB_8888);  
         Canvas canvas =  new   Canvas(result);  
         canvas.drawARGB(0, 0xff, 0, 0);  
         Paint paint = new Paint();  
         paint.setAntiAlias(true);   
         paint.setFilterBitmap(true);   
         paint.setColor( context.getResources().getColor(R.color.id));  //use your background color
         paint.setAlpha(200);  
         canvas.drawCircle(size/2, size/2, size/2, paint);
         paint.setAlpha(255);  
         paint.setTextSize(9);  
         paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);  //use your text color
         float textWidth = paint.measureText(text);   
         FontMetrics fm = paint.getFontMetrics();    
         float textHeight = (float)(fm.descent +  fm.ascent)

         canvas.drawText(text, (size-textWidth) /2.0f,(size-textHeight)/2.0f, paint); 


         final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0,size, size);  
         paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));  
         canvas.drawBitmap(result, rect, rect, paint);   
         return result;  
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

//usage: genBitMapforAnim("5", 48)

```
protected Bitmap genBitMapforAnim(String itemCode, int size) {  
         String text = itemCode.length() >= 5 ? itemCode.substring(0, 5) : itemCode;  
         Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(size*2,size*2, Config.ARGB_8888);  
         Canvas canvas =  new   Canvas(result);  
         canvas.drawARGB(0, 0xff, 0, 0);  
         Paint paint = new Paint();  
         paint.setAntiAlias(true);   
         paint.setFilterBitmap(true);   
         paint.setColor(Color.RED);  //use your background color
         paint.setAlpha(200);  
         canvas.drawCircle(size/2, size/2, size/2, paint);
         paint.setAlpha(255);  
         paint.setTextSize(9);  
         paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);  //use your text color
         float textWidth = paint.measureText(text);   
         FontMetrics fm = paint.getFontMetrics();    
         float textHeight = (float)(fm.descent +  fm.ascent)

         canvas.drawText(text, (size-textWidth) /2.0f,(size-textHeight)/2.0f, paint); 


         final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0,size, size);  
         paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));  
         canvas.drawBitmap(result, rect, rect, paint);   
         return result;  
    }
```

Comment: I am expecting to see R.drawable or R.color or something from resources.... That's what I wanted and mentioned in question as well..... DISAPPOINTMENT :(